# Print only select keys, instead of all key,value pair?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a code in which I print all keys, and value of the hash. I wanna make it configurable, so that instead of all keys it prints only the required keys. Suppose I have keys k1, k2, k3...k20. And I want to print k1, k3, k8....k15, k18. What's the best possible way to go about this?

This is the relevant code snippet -:

```
   <%@order_items.each do |order_item|%>
        <h5>Order Item</h5>
        <%order_item.each do |key,value|%>

          <table cellspacing=2>

            <tr><td><%=key.capitalize%>: </td> <td><%= value %></td></tr>

          </table>
        <%end%>
      <%end%>
```

Comment: the keys that you want to keep are from some sequence or can be any set of values the user provides?

Comment: @Arindam - Keys can be any set of values that the user provides. These keys actually correspond to columns from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do also this

```
<% [1,3,8,15,18].each do |key|; value = order_item[key] %>
```

Comment: <% [:id,:order_id,:status].each do |key|; value = order_item[key] %> is working. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

With something like that :

```
<% order_item.select{|k,_| [1,3,8,15,18].include?(k)}.each do |key,value| %>
```

Comment: Note that in ruby 1.9.3 it returns a hash (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select), but in ruby 1.8.7 it returns an array (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-select) which needs to be converted back to a hash before applying the `|key, value|` block

Comment: @Arindam it actually works in `1.8.7`. It is converted to an `Array` but they will be passed as pair since the select generated an array of arrays -an array of pairs-.

Comment: Yeah good point. I personally would not like that kind of code floating around. `an array that passes off as a hash` due to specific local implementation? Not a good practice. hence pointed it out, so that the innocent might not be incriminated at some point in time :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
class Hash
  def select_keys(*args)
    select {|k,v| args.include?(k) }
  end
end
```

And then you can call:

```
h.select_keys(1,3,8,15,18)
```

OR

You can just use:

```
hash.slice(1,3,8,15,18)
 # => { '1' => 'value1', '3' => 'value2', '8' => 'value3', '15' => 'value4', '18' => 'value5' }
```